# Adding IPv6 to domU guest

Tags: linux, networking, ipv6, xen

I am looking for help on getting IPv6 to my Xen domU's. I currently have one 6in4 tunnel from HE for each guest and would like to consolidate that to one on the dom0. But I am not set on that-- I am completely open to suggestions.

Based on my research both here and on Google, I am not finding anything great. For what it is worth, the dom0 is running Centos 5.8 and Xen 3.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds good to me. Set up radvd on the dom0 to advise the routable /64 they give you and have the domUs get an address from it.

Comment: Any suggestions on securing those advertisements to only my guests? I don't want to advertise to anyone outside of my host machine.

Comment: Restrict it to the bridge device.

Comment: Ideally that would be peth, correct?

Comment: Not really sure; I moved to KVM years ago.